QAudioSink started and reads data, but doesn't play sound
I am attempting to use the QAudioSink type from Qt 6.7.2 to play procedurally-generated sound clips. I've written a short piece of code that attempts to play white noise. It seems like the QAudioSink object is indeed reading data and in the active state, but I don't hear anything played through my speakers.
Here's the code:
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioSink>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QtTypes>
#include <QFile>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/* Sample rate; chosen Arbitrarily and Capriciously. */
const int kSampleRate = 11025;

/* Class that holds a data buffer of random values, serving as a white
 * noise source.
 */
class NoiseWave: public QIODevice {
public:
    /* Fills a buffer with pseudorandom values. */
    NoiseWave() {
        for (int i = 0; i < kBufferSize; i++) {
            buffer[i] = std::rand() % 256;
        }
    }

protected:
    /* Hand back the data in the buffer. */
    qint64 readData(char* data, qint64 maxSize) override {
        std::cout << "Requesting " << maxSize << " bytes." << std::endl;
        if (maxSize > kBufferSize) maxSize = kBufferSize;

        std::cout << "Giving back " << maxSize << std::endl;
        std::memcpy(data, buffer, maxSize);

        return maxSize;
    }

    /* Only readable, not writable */
    qint64 writeData(const char*, qint64) override {
        return -1;
    }

private:
    /* Buffer holding raw data. */
    static const int kBufferSize = 10000;
    quint8 buffer[kBufferSize];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /* Set the audio format. */
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(kSampleRate);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::UInt8);

    /* Get an audio sink we can write to. */
    auto* audio = new QAudioSink(format, nullptr);

    /* Make the noise pattern to repeat. */
    auto* wave  = new NoiseWave();
    wave->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    /* Start the sound. */
    audio->start(wave);

    /* Print basic stats. */
    std::cout << "Audio state is now  " << audio->state() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Audio error code is " << audio->error() << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}

Here is the output from the program. (I've added the bits in square brackets to indicate the passage of time; that's not in the actual program output.)
Audio state is now  0
Audio error code is 0
Requesting 16384 bytes.
Giving back 10000

[ ... time passes ... ]

Requesting 16384 bytes.
Giving back 10000

[ ... time passes ... ]

Requesting 16384 bytes.
Giving back 10000

[ ... time passes ... ]

Requesting 16384 bytes.
Giving back 10000

From what I'm seeing here it looks like the audio device is in active mode (QtAudio::ActiveState has enum value 0) and there is no error. It's also clear that the NoiseWave::readData function is being invoked repeatedly and at about the rate I would expect given the sampling rate. However, there's no audio playing.
This code runs cleanly under valgrind, so I don't think the issue is a memory error.
Can anyone provide guidance as to why I'm not hearing anything?
Update, Aug 2: It seems like changing the constructor call magically fixes things. Replacing this line:
auto* audio = new QAudioSink(format, nullptr);

with this one:
auto* audio = new QAudioSink(QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput(), 
                             format, nullptr);

suddenly fixes everything. However, I'm not sure why this is the case. The documentation for the two-argument QAudioSink constructor says the following:

QAudioSink::QAudioSink(const QAudioFormat &format = QAudioFormat(), QObject *parent = nullptr)
Construct a new audio output and attach it to parent. The default audio output device is used with the output format parameters.

Given this, it's unclear to me why explicitly specifying that the audio device is QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput() would have any effect. The documentation for QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput() says that it "[r]eturns the default audio output device." Why would specifying this have any effect?

Have you tried with a more standard sample rate, such as 44100 or 48000? Note that you may need to override other QIODevice functions (for instance, isSequential()).

@musicamante Thanks for the suggestions! Changing the sample rate to 44100 produces the same results, though the NoiseWave::readData is queried more frequently as expected. Overriding isSequential to return true did not result in any changes. (Perhaps there are other member functions I need to override?)

Unfortunately the documentation for QIODevice usage in QtMultimedia is scarce. I cannot do a test right now, but just a few hours ago I had similar issues trying to use a QIODevice with QMediaPlayer. After some tests I found out an acceptable combination based on ReadOnly|Unbuffered open mode, overriding bytesAvailable() and pos() (for some strange reason, when returning true from isSequential() I had to return -1 from pos()).

Note that I also tried subclassing QFile, opened with a regular file, but returning arbitrary data, and for some reason it worked. I then used it as a reference to understand how to eventually implement the custom QIODevice subclass.

I'm starting to wonder whether the issue is with my system. I tried running the Qt-provided QAudioSink demo on my machine and didn't get any sound from that either. However, the QMediaPlayer type seems to be able to play audio from a file just fine. If you have a minute, can you try running the exact code I have above on your system and see if anything comes back? If so, then I know the issue is that something is up with my system.

Sorry, the only system that I could use to test Qt6 is a VM that I'm currently (lazily) upgrading in my spare time. I also have almost no experience with C++, so it would probably be easier to me to port your code to PySide/PyQt so that I could eventually do further changes and tests more easily; still, I doubt I'll be able to do it before the end of the week, and I'm not making any promise.

@musicamante No worries!

I just tried it. I don't get anything just state = 3, error = 0.

You should verify if your default device supports the audio format being used. The QAudioDevice::isFormatSupported() function will provide the answer. Additionally, you should use standard sample rates for raw audio (e.g., 8 kHz, 16 kHz, 44.1 kHz, etc.). I don't think Qt performs resampling to match device capabilities.

@tunglt Thanks for the suggestion. I didn’t include the code that performs this check, but prior to creating the QAudioSink I used the appropriate Qt API to check whether the device supported the format, which it does.

Did you handle error states in your program? Some devices need to be reset and resumed when errors occur (e.g., device not ready, buffer overflow, etc.). Is the volume set to the correct level?

To the best of my knowledge no errors were triggered. I can update the question with code for a listener handling state changes. It only triggered once, when the state changed to active, and no errors were reported.

In theory, if the sink is not able to play with the selected audio device, no reading should happen at all. I'd suggest you a couple of tests, though: 1. try to generate a physical file with appropriate data (and length) and directly use QFile with it; 2. create the sink with an explicit QAudioDevice (see the QMediaDevices static functions) and checking isFormatSupported(). I suppose you're on Linux, do you use PulseAudio and/or Jack? Can you check what low level audio backend is used in the Qt build? If it's set to PulseAudio, you can check pavucontrol if the playback tab shows a new entry.

@musicamante Setting the explicit output device in the QAudioSink constructor to QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput() fixed it! But that's so strange - the documentation says that the two-argument constructor uses "[t]he default audio output device [...] with the output format parameters." Why wasn't it doing this the first time around?

@templatetypedef Good! I don't know why, but I can make some guesses: 1. maybe, the constructor you used actually queries all the available audio devices (in some arbitrary order based on the backend) and gets the first available that explicitly supports that format; if you're on ALSA, it's possible it got a "virtual device" (check asound.conf); 2. it's probably a bug: remember that the QtMultimedia module has been rewritten from scratch since Qt6, reintroduced "only" 3 years ago with 6.2, and it still is under active development, with lots of changes and bug report/fix activity, including »

@templatetypedef many regressions (I've read about a lot happened in 6.7); 3. the docs are simply wrong: many new classes introduced in Qt6 lack the proper and thorough documentation we're normally used to with Qt, many classes have inaccurate docs (not reflecting changes in the implementation), some are almost undocumented, and a few are even missing some functions/slots/signals/properties completely (like the pageRendered signal of QPdfPageRenderer).

@templatetypedef Baumflaum's answer seems to confirm my assumptions, and it clearly seems a bug, both in implementation and documentation. I've just reported a bug. Let's wait for any reply... yet, it's August ;-)

@templatetypedef I finally had some time to make a basic test, using a wav file (exported as raw). Despite the code notes below, I'm able to get QAudioSink working by only specifying the format (no device provided), which makes me think that the platform implementation changes the result of that constructor. What OS and Qt version are you using? I'm able to play raw files on Linux with PyQt (Qt 6.6.1) and PySide (Qt 6.6.3), but I know that some changes have been introduced in 6.7.

@musicamante Qt 6.7.2 on Linux.

@templatetypedef Are you able to check with 6.6 (even on a vm)? Do you see any further/different output in the terminal? Maybe consider adding further info on my report (as said, my C++ knowledge is quite limited, you may be able to provide a more accurate insight).

To answer your edit. It seems to be a bug either in the documentation or the code; choose one.
Code snippet from QAudioSink (qaudiosink.cpp Qt6.7.2):
/*!
    Construct a new audio output and attach it to \a parent.
    The default audio output device is used with the output
    \a format parameters.
*/
QAudioSink::QAudioSink(const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent)
    : QAudioSink({}, format, parent) // <<<<<< Bug here
{
}

/*!
    Construct a new audio output and attach it to \a parent.
    The device referenced by \a audioDevice is used with the output
    \a format parameters.
*/
QAudioSink::QAudioSink(const QAudioDevice &audioDevice, const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{
    d = QPlatformMediaIntegration::instance()->mediaDevices()->audioOutputDevice(format, audioDevice, parent);
    if (d)
        connect(d, &QPlatformAudioSink::stateChanged, this, [this](QAudio::State state) {
            // if the signal has been emitted from another thread,
            // the state may be already changed by main one
            if (state == d->state())
                emit stateChanged(state);
        });
    else
        qWarning() << ("No audio device detected");
}

Despite describing in the documentation "The default audio output device is used with the output format parameters" the code calls the default constructor of the QAudioDevice class which is a "null QAudioDevice object".
P.S.: You could argue the default audio output device is the null QAudioDevice, since the "default" constructor constructs a null object. But I'm being a devils advocate here. ;)
Edit1:
It seems my analysis was not deep enough as shown in the comments in the original question. QAudioSinks constructor calls QPlatformMediaIntegration::instance()->mediaDevices()->audioOutputDevice(format, audioDevice, parent). There if a null QAudioDevice is passed, a valid one is selected like that qplatformmediadevices.cpp:
QAudioDevice info = deviceInfo;
if (info.isNull())
    info = audioOutputs().value(0);

While the implementation of QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput() looks like that:
QAudioDevice QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput()
{
    const auto outputs = audioOutputs();
    if (outputs.isEmpty())
        return {};
    for (const auto &info : outputs)
        if (info.isDefault())
            return info;
    return outputs.value(0);
}

So it seems the code is buggy and it should be info = QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput();.

I checked the sources too, and I also thought that constructor probably assigned a null audio output (despite the docs), but I couldn't be sure about the actual meaning of that {} based on my limited C++ knowledge, so I didn't mention it to the OP. As you demonstrate, that constructor uses a null device, not the "default one", so there's really no argue here: the "default device" is a possibly valid device, the null one never is. Therefore, as I supposed, it's a bug, both about doc accuracy and API implementation. No matter what, it's quite important and worth reporting.

Reported QTBUG-127793.

@musicamante Well after all it seems my initial answer wasn't going deep enough. Still buggy, but not as bad. ;)

Interesting. I thought that an underlying platform plugin would have been in order, but I wasn't able to find more about it due to my limited C++ knowledge. I'd suggest you to sign up to the Qt bugreport system and provide further details, as you can certainly provide more appropriate details than I could.
